# can I be helped? my querey should = something like .000534 however I get 0

Tags: postgresql, count, cast

My query result should be 0.000534, but I'm getting 0.

Please help me.

```
psql -Upostgres -dcans -c \
    'select (select COUNT(*)
             FROM brd.gaf_info
             where can_piecesre_sucbattery = 'pr' 
               and gaf_start_date > '2019-11-13 01:01:01.754'
            ) /
            (select COUNT(*)
             FROM brd.gaf_info
             where gaf_start_date > '2019-11-13 01:01:01.754'
            );'
```

Comment: Your expression is `integer / integer`, so the result is integer. You must CAST your COUNTs to some floating-point datatype before divide.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I mean in general. The specific datatype is unimportant.

Answer (score 3):

You are using integer division (more precisely `bigint`) which yields not fractional values. You need to cast one value to numeric in order to get what you want:

```
select (select COUNT(*)
         FROM brd.gaf_info
         where can_piecesre_sucbattery = 'pr' 
           and gaf_start_date > '2019-11-13 01:01:01.754'
        )::numeric /
        (select COUNT(*)
         FROM brd.gaf_info
         where gaf_start_date > '2019-11-13 01:01:01.754'
        );
```

Additionally, please note that with the help of a `FILTER` clause you can calculate the result without subqueries, since the same table is used in both subqueries, and one of the conditions is also the same. You just need to move the other condition to the `FILTER` clause, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE can_piecesre_sucbattery = 'pr')::numeric
     / COUNT(*)
FROM brd.gaf_info
WHERE gaf_start_date > '2019-11-13 01:01:01.754';
```